# Looking for query run against table to output number of users and number of semicolon-separated items per user

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a table that looks something like the following:

```
|Id|Name                  |FormIds                                           |
|--|----------------------|--------------------------------------------------|
|1 |john.doe@blah.co      |32132;32323;232323;424323;2323;23232;2323         |
|2 |jane.doe@whatever.co  |32323;11123;11321                                 |
|3 |joe.blow@yeet.co      |22324                                             |
```

I'm looking for a query that will give me the number of distinct FormId's per user and last row showing total users count and total formids:
Example output:

```
Names                 |TotalFormIdsPerUser                                      
----------------------|--------------------------
john.doe@blah.co      |7         
jane.doe@whatever.co  |3 
joe.blow@yeet.co      |1
----------------------|--------------------------
3                     |11
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: can you show expected with text

Comment: Sorry.. Submitted prematurely.  Edited to include the expected output example.

Comment: Store your data properly and you won't have this issue

Comment: @DaleK Kind of an ignorant comment, but ok.  This is a big, old table on a DB that was created years ago by another team for a project our team recently inherited. We had no influence over how they designed data layer.

Comment: Since you didn't tell us that up front we don't know. And a lot of newbies make this kind of design mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string_split` (For splitting the FormIds) and a CTE

Then you use `group by` to find the sum and sum total.

```
with _list as (
        select FormIds,Name,s.value value_
        from Testf a
        cross apply(select * from string_split(a.FormIds,';'))s
)
select Name as Names, c as TotalFormIdsPerUser                                      
from (
select  a.Name,count(a.value_) as c,1 as Type
from  _list a
group by a.Name

union all
select  
         cast( count(distinct a.Name) as varchar(100)) as name
        ,count(a.value_) as c
        ,2 as Type
from  _list a
)s
order by Type, c desc
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Jj_mlTfl)

Comment: This is great!! **Thank you abolfazi sadeghi and Dale K!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**